# legal to test the security of your own wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have read multiple articles online that suggest that I test **my own** wifi network in order to see if it can be broken into, for security purposes of making sure that people can't use my home wifi without my permission. Most of the articles suggest using different tools, some of which use things like "packet injection". Before I test my network out, is downloading these tools to test the security of **my own** home wifi network legal?

Comment: If you have legal concerns, you should probably talk to a legal expert, not computer enthusiasts.

Comment: This might depend on which country you live in.

Comment: Are you afraid the wifi home-network police will come and arrest you after they've found out what you've done?

Answer (score 3):

sure, it's your network. You have right to do whatever you want with your own network as long as it doesn't affect others